# Software Sources - Additional Drivers - Apply and Revert buttons grayed out

Tags: lubuntu, software-sources, nvidia-geforce, additional-drivers, lxqt

I've got Lubuntu 22.04 (Ubuntu with LXQT), NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940MX] graphics card and `535.54.03` driver. From past few months *Apply Changes* and *Revert* buttons are grayed out in *Software Sources - Additional Drivers*, so I am stuck to `nvidia-driver-535` option. The rest of the options (old nvidia drivers plus `X.Org opensource`) are selectable, but I cannot apply the changes because of the disabled buttons.

I'm happy with the current driver, but I'd like to have the option to choose another one in the future.

Any idea how to solve this issue?